# Dúvida na Criação de um app / Servidor / Notificações

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, apache-cordova

Estou com um projeto de desenvolver um app Android, usando Phonegap + jQueryMobile, já consegui criar a interface, a mudança de telas e etc.
Agora vem a parte difícil para mim: o Backend :(

Vou citar o que preciso fazer e se possível, gostaria de sugestões, para que o que pensei possa funcionar, e o que eu preciso estudar e de qual forma eu teria uma curva de aprendizado menor.

1. Tela inicial, irá solicitar login e senha
2. Na sequência, vai aparecer uma listagem de pessoas, obtidas através do servidor
3. Nessa listagem, eu terei opções para enviar notificações aos responsáveis das pessoas que constam na lista
4. Em um outro app cliente com phonegap, preciso que essa notificação chegue ao responsável

Creio que para tal, eu teria que criar um "admin" com cadastro das pessoas que irão logar, com a listagem das pessoas que devem aparecer na lista e algo que relacione os responsáveis para que possam receber as notificações.

Recentemente vi um pouco sobre Ruby on Rails e achei a curva de aprendizado interessante, seria possível eu criar essa aplicação, contendo a parte de Backend com Ruby?

Comment: Cássio, existem muitas variáveis envolvidas nessa sua dúvida, o que torna uma possível resposta bastante ampla. O que você vai precisar é ler um pouco sobre *webservice* ([*RESTful*](https://www.airpair.com/ruby-on-rails/posts/building-a-restful-api-in-a-rails-application), por exemplo), pois seu aplicativo vai fazer as solicitações de dados para ele. Depois que você desenvolver esse *webservice*, ai sim você vai entrar nesses 4 pontos citados, os quais pode perguntar separadamente caso tenha dificuldade de encontrar uma solução, tenha alguma dúvida ou erro no desenvolvimento.

Comment: Sim é possível e é bem comum fazer esse tipo de backend com Rails.

Comment: Muito obrigado Paulo e Alex, com certeza me ajudou bastante! Grande abraço!

Comment: As vezes Rails é muito grande pra fazer uma API RESTful como você quer (é como usar um canhão para matar uma mosca), eu recomendaria você dar uma olhada em outros frameworks feitos em Ruby como [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/), [Grape](http://intridea.github.io/grape/) ou [Cuba](http://cuba.is/) e continuar aproveitado das gems que você usaria normalmente no Rails.

Comment: Obrrigado @iTSangar com certeza não deixarei de fazer uma pesquisa sobre os Frameworks informados! Muito obrigado mesmo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar perfeitamente uma aplicação Rails para o seu backend. Quanto ao sistema de login, recomendo fortemente o [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), que é mantido pela [PlataformaTec](http://plataformatec.com.br/) que é uma empresa brasileira com uma importante atuação na comunidade de Rails.

Se quiser ver outras opções para sistema de autenticação de usuário, você pode usar o [Ruby ToolBox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authentication) para comparar quais são as soluções mais usadas. De qualquer forma, Devise é a primeira da lista ;)

Por fim, se você optar por seguir com Rails, você terá que criar uma API RESTful para comunicação com sua aplicação mobile. Essa pode ser a parte mais tricky, então recomendo novas leituras e que você volte a perguntar conforme for necessitando de ajuda.

Antes de meter a mão na massa com Rails, experimenta dar uma lida sobre [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/) ou, melhor ainda, dê uma boa olhada em [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/). Parece que Meteor atenderia perfeitamente a sua demanda, mas é melhor dar uma lida mais completa no assunto. Veja esse artigo:

[Meteor 0.9.2: Building iOS and Android mobile apps with PhoneGap](https://www.meteor.com/blog/2014/09/15/meteor-092-iOS-Android-mobile-apps-phonegap-cordova)

Não respondo a sua pergunta, mas espero ter ajudado \o/

Comment: Obrigado amigo, irei estudar sim! Conforme for surgindo as dúvidas, volto a publicar ou criar novas perguntas! Muito obrigado!